# Capturar el stdout de un proceso en una variable

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo la siguiente duda como capturo el stdout para usarlo mas adelante (al igualarlo a data me lo imprime vacio);

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var data = "5";
var child = exec('java -jar DproRan.jar',
  function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
    data = stdout;
    if(error !== null){
      console.log("Error -> "+error);
    }
  }
);

console.log(data);

function imprimir(stdout) {
  if(stdout!=null) {
    var ss = stdout.split("_");
    console.log(ss[1],ss[3],ss[5]);

  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }
}
```

Comment: javascript o java?

Comment: en javascript ,

Comment: @Brayan Agregué la etiqueta [tag:nodejs] (de lo contrario, se asume que es JavaScript en un navegador).

Answer (score 1):

Buenas @Brayan,

Estas accediendo a la variable "data" antes de que sea cargada. Para hacer uso correcto de NodeJS deberías tener en cuenta que las llamadas se hacen de forma asíncrona a no ser que se fuerce lo contrario.

Primero te voy a indicar en tu código por qué no se ha mostrado nada al hacer "console.log(data);":

```html
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var data = "5";
var child = exec('java -jar DproRan.jar',
// Esta funcion anónima es la que recibe el resultado de ejecutar el comando, y aquí es donde verás stdout por primera vez. 
function (error, stdout, stderr){ 
  console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
  data = stdout;
  if(error !== null){
    console.log("Error -> "+error);
  }
});
// Data se initializa a 5, y se sobreescribe con stdout una vez que el método "exec" termine y se ejecute la función anónima que se ha definido como retorno.
// Se va a ejecutar esto antes de que se le asigne el valor de stdout.
console.log(data);


// Este método no se llama en tu código.
function imprimir(stdout)
{
  if(stdout!=null)
  {
      var ss = stdout.split("_");
      console.log(ss[1],ss[3],ss[5]);

  }
  else
  {
      console.log("error");
  }
}
```

Para evitar que te ocurra esto, que es un error muy común cuando se empieza con Node JS tienes que entender como funciona, y hacer uso correcto de el. Lo más adecuado sería algo parecido a esto:

```html
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var data = "5";
var child = exec('java -jar DproRan.jar',
// Esta funcion anónima es la que recibe el resultado de ejecutar el comando, y aquí es donde verás stdout por primera vez. 
function (error, stdout, stderr){ 
  if(error !== null || stderr !== null){
    console.log("Error -> " + error);
    console.log("StdError -> " + stderr);
  }else{
    console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
    data = stdout;
    // Si quieres comprobar la variable data una vez que se ha cargado con la respuesta de stdout tienes que hacerlo de aquí en adelante.
    // Por ejemplo lo vamos a comprobar al finalizar la función a la que se va a llamar ahora.
    imprimir();
  }
});
// Verás que se suprime el comando console.log(data), ya que desde aquí no estaría nunca accesible esa variable cargada con stdout.


// Este método ahora sí se llama desde la función anónima que tiene el método "exec" a modo de callback.
// Verás que ya no se pasa variable por parámetro y hace uso de data.
function imprimir(){
  if(data!=null){
      var ss = data.split("_");
      console.log(ss[1],ss[3],ss[5]);

  }else{
      console.log("Error: Variable data es null.");
  }
  
  // Aunque la variable data se ha usado a lo largo de este método, voy a añadir el comando "console.log(data);" para que lo veas más claramente.
  console.log(data);
}
```